# Consider the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=(x+2)^3$. The set $f^{−1}((−1,1))$ is? (For Improvement)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This question may be related to determining one to one functions under algebric tests.

1) A function $f$ is said to be one-one or (injective) if;

$f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ which implies $x_1 = x_2$

2) Lemma 2. The function $f$ is one-to-one if and only if
$\forall x_1, \forall x_2, x_1$ is not equal to $x_2$ implies $f(x_1)$ is not equal to $f(x_2)$.

Would I be right to state the set is $(-1,1)$?

Comment: Yes both for the stated just failed to type them well. Both are powers

Comment: The function is one to one and onto, hence has an inverse, can you find the inverse function?

Comment: I asks what set is the image of the set $(-1,1)$ under $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Please look at the way I reformatted the title to see if that is what you intended.

Comment: $f^{-1}((-1,1))\neq(-1,1).$  Note that $f^{-1}(0) = -2\notin(-1,1)$

Comment: What does the graph of the function look like? If you haven't plotted it yet, do so now: I think it will be enlightening.

Comment: The notation $f^{-1}S,$ equivalently $f^{-1}(S),$ usually denotes $\{x: f(x)\in S\}$ regardless of whether $f$ is, or is not, $1$-to-$1$..... In your Q we have $x\in f^{-1}((-1,1))\iff $ $ f(x)\in (-1,1)\iff$ $\iff  (x+2)^3\in (-1,1)\iff $ $-1<(x+2)^3<1.$

Comment: Note that the graph of $y = (x + 2)^3$ is obtained from the graph of $y = x^3$ by shifting the graph of $y = x^3$ two units to the left.  For the function $g(x) = x^3$, it is true that $g^{-1}((-1, 1)) = (-1, 1)$, so what does that tell you about $f^{-1}((-1, 1))$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f(x) = (x + 2)^3$.
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}((-1, 1)) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) \in (-1, 1)\} && \text{by definition of $f^{-1}((-1, 1))$}\\
                & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -1 < f(x) < 1\} && \text{by definition of an open interval}\\
                & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -1 < (x + 2)^3 < 1\} && \text{substitution}\\
                & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -1 < x + 2 < 1\} && \text{take cube roots}\\
              & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -3 < x < -1\} && \text{subtraction}\\
              & = (-3, 1) && \text{by definition of an open interval}
\end{align*}
where we have used the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing to conclude that $f(x_1) < f(x_2) \iff x_1 < x_2$.

The answer would have been $(-1, 1)$ if we wanted to find $g^{-1}((-1, 1))$ for the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = x^3$.

The transformation $g(x) \to g(x + 2) = f(x)$ translates the graph of $g(x) = x^3$ two units to the left, so $f^{-1}((-1, 1)) = (-1 - 2, 1 - 2) = (-3, 1)$, as you can verify by examining its graph.

[image: horizontal_translation_of_cube_function_graph]